# Basic usage of fixtures and loop

Tags: cypress

I would LOVE to making this look so much better.

The screenshot below works, but you can see that it is hardcoded:

#### 1: How to turn this into a smarter solution?

[image]

I guess adding these 5 numbers in an fixture should do it, but how do I make a loop of it?

_

#### 2: How to make this number divided by X numbers

[image]

I wanted 100 to be divided as well with the length of the "array" above. So the X funds will have be evenly distributed

-
Thanks for taking your time

Comment: Hi! Please consider using the image upload provided in the stack overflow interface. It uses imgur as well, but the domain is `i.stack.imgur.com`. `imgur.com` is blocked at a number of workplaces, but `stack.imgur.com` often is not.

Answer (score 5):

In case someone is still wondering how to loop fixtures here is an example:

Let's assume you've saved those 5-digit numbers to a file cypress/fixtures/numbers.json

```
[
43214,
23423,
95373,
23593,
43434
]
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
  cy.fixture('number').then(numbers => {
        for(let number in numbers) {
            // Write the number to input field
            cy.get('input[id="fundId]"').type(number)
        }
    });
```

Rembember that the `cypress.fixture()` searches fixtures from `cypress/fixtures` -directory by default. You can override this in cypress.json by using `fixturesFolder` option.

More info about fixtures can be found in the documentation: [cypress.io - fixtures](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Syntax)